# Get Frame at half of video with opencv

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

is there a way to get a frame form opencv, but around half of the video (for example if the video is 10 minutes I want to save a frame at 5:00 minutes). I have already seen something on the internet but everyone just goes ahead frame by frame. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```py
import cv2

# Read the Video (Change the filename as per your file)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

# Get the total number of frames
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
half_point = length//2 # Approximately half if number of frames are odd

# Set the reader to the given frame number (half_point)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, half_point)

# Read the frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Release the file pointer
cap.release()
```

And you should get the half-point frame in the variable `frame`.